# How to analyse the performance of Mathematica on this function?

Tags: performance-tuning

Using

```
f[n_] := Sum[1/(Sqrt[k] + Sqrt[k + 1]), {k, 1, n}]
```

to analyze the well-know series...

I noticed a sudden performance drop (on my outdated PC hardware ) around n=14.

```
f[14] // FullSimplify
```

Is there away to overcome this? Memoization comes to mind.

What would be a method to monitor performance of such a function?

Not sure how to go ahead with this.

Comment: Is this a toy problem to ask about timing performance, since Mathematica can perform the sum analytically?
`Sum[1/(Sqrt[k] + Sqrt[k + 1]), {k, 1, n}]` to give `-1 + Sqrt[1 + n]`
Additionally, are you sure you're timing the summation itself and not `FullSimplify`? The timing results up to n=40 seem reasonable to me.

Comment: With `f[n_] := f[n] = Sum[1/(Sqrt[k] + Sqrt[k + 1]), {k, 1, n}];
f[40]; // RepeatedTiming` I get 4 10^-7 sec what seems rather fast.

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides is right: the slowness comes from `FullSimplify`, not from `Sum`. You can use [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) instead of `FullSimplify`: the former is more precisely targeted to the task.

Comment: ```Remove["Global`*"]``` then try `Total[Table[1/(Sqrt[k] + Sqrt[k + 1]), {k, n}]]` or do the Sum with `Method->"Procedural"` ignoring the `FullSimplify` - you will find that in both cases f[14] is initially very fast, but the second time you run it is much slower. Not sure why but possibly caused by some kind of caching in mathematica's automatic simplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a toy problem: a fast way would be to [memoize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) and [root-reduce](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) at every step,

```
Clear[f];
f[0] = 0;
f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] =
  RootReduce[f[n - 1] + 1/(Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[n + 1])]

f[100] // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.514451, -1 + Sqrt[101]}    *)
```

Comment: Generate a sequence `seq = f /@ Range[6]` then looking at its form use `Sqrt[FindSequenceFunction[(seq + 1)^2, n]] - 1` Or, since you have the recursion, you can use `RSolve`, i.e., `Clear[f]; f[n] /. RSolve[{f[n] == f[n - 1] + 1/(Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[n + 1]), f[0] == 0}, f[n], n][[1]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon of course; but I was assuming that this is a toy problem.

Comment: Most of my problems are ( thank G. ) "toy" problems.